# Touching the opposite gender by way of an object

Tags: halacha, negia

Is it permissible to touch someone of the opposite sex with an object (for example: to get their attention)?

Comment: I heard in person from a rabbi that it is permissible. (I have no source, though.)

Comment: What about, can you touch her skin to get her attention?

Comment: I've heard that Rav Shamshon Refael Hirsch was Matir shaking the other gender's hands while wearing gloves.

Comment: possible dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12512/759

Comment: I don't think it's allowed for your your spouse during niddah, however. (At least according to hareidi practice. Don't know what the actual halacha is. cylor.)

Answer (score 2):

The prohibition only applies to "derech chibah", so even without an object it would not be forbidden, though in practice it would not be recommended. However, with an object wouldn't be a problem.

See the beginning of this Hakirah article by R.Y. Henkin:
http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%204%20Henkin.pdf

While poskim argue over what a handshake is classified as, they agree that something that isn't derech chibah is not forbidden.